# what is the difference between asp.net 5 starter web vs MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I have visual studio 2015 preview. When I select web project inside it shows options with MVC and asp.net starter web. What is the difference between the both? Which is better and why?

Answer (score 1):

MVC is the current stable release of MVC (Version 5) - ASP.NET 4.x

Starter Web is all the new vnext MVC (Version 6) - ASP.NET 5

Those are very different, both in concept, structure, workflow and project type. I recommend you to read https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5

While mvc6 (starter web) has a lot of new features and concepts, it's still a preview and not ready for production. (Expect a RC **at least** on summer) and some pieces are still being developed, meaning that some (or lots) may change before it makes to the final version.

**ASP.NET 5 (mvc6 starter web) is BETA bits.**